# Hibernate session managment in Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, caching

I'm developing web application with Spring MVC and Hibernate, with few entity classes, some of them associated and there are many methods which involves operation on multiple entities (for example updating two entities at once) and some methods appears multiple times (like getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() (which I think should be cached in Hibernate first level cache to avoid redundant queries, so shoud be invoking in one session). Currently, I have sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() in every method with database operations. I read that session objects are not thread-safe and should be closed as soon as transaction is complete, but also that setting

```
 <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
      thread
 </property>
```

bounds session to the context and thus session getting by getCurrentSession() doesn't need to be closed, so I'm bit confused about using getCurrentSession(). I want to implement best session managment system to avoid thread-safety issues and make use of Hibernate first level cache.

Comment: Have you looked into Spring CRUDRepository or JPARepository? You can Utilize those which can utilize hibernate in the background and you wont have to call session factory every time. Just Autowire the repository and you're good to go.

Comment: Never heard of it. Well, I don't explicitly call session factory, I'm using generic abstract class which entity specialized dao classes extends. I only call session (but not explicitly with calling session factory), when creating  query.

Comment: Springs repositories can create the queries in a much cleaner and more efficient ways and does a lot of stuff in the background that you no longer need to worry about.

Comment: But will it also take care of concurrency control?

Comment: yes. Since it can use hibernate it has access to all of hibernates concurrency controls